# (How to access) GWT's Datagrid's Scrollbar

Tags: events, gwt, datagrid

So i can add events for example? I want to have the data grid automatically load more records as you reach the end of the scroll bar (like the showcase example, with the only difference that i'm using a datagrid)

Answer (score 0):

use OnScroll Event to load more data .